# How should I treat variables that aren't necessarily class properties but are used by several methods?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, language-agnostic

I occasionally find myself with several methods in a class that all require the same data (for example, a query object). Typically, there will be one public method with a generic name like `parseReport()` which in turn delegates work out to several private methods and finally returns the finished product:

```
public function parseReport( queryObject ) {
    queryObject = correctDatesAndTimes( queryObject );
    queryObject = sortByCusomter( queryObject );
    queryObject = buildHierarchy( queryObject );

    return queryObject;
}

private function correctDatesAndTimes( queryObject ) {
    // do some stuff

    return queryObject;
}

private function sortByCusomter( queryObject ) {
    // do some stuff

    return queryObject;
}

private function buildHierarchy( queryObject ) {
    // do some stuff

    return queryObject;
}
```

So my question is, should my `queryObject` be a class-level property that all of my methods will reference rather than passing it through as an argument to the method each time it is called?

Comment: Do those functions mutate "this"? If not, then this whole group of functions is quite possibly thread-safe, but would not be if you change them all to set a property.

Comment: They don't currently modify "this" at all, their work in its entirety is done on `queryObject` which is passed in from other locations and then returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a case like this, queryObject should not be a class property. If you look at it, you actually have one big function that is split in several smaller functions. If it was one big function, you wouldn't make a class property of it.

Data belongs in a class property, when the data is actually a part of the class. Remember that 
a class definition is the encapsulating of both data and behavior.

Comment: Thanks - That was my thought as well, but it felt weird passing it around the class like that.

Answer (score 1):

In your example you need to pass the query object as a parameter, as it will be changed inside the private function.

Additionally putting it into a private property will give you headaches if you go multithreaded.